# Importing Vitamio library to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to put together a small project that streams rtmp.  I happened upon ;
http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/stream-rtmp-live-android/

and

http://karanbalkar.com/2014/11/tutorial-92-live-streaming-using-vitamio-in-android/

These are instructions for setting up in Android Studio and eclipse, however I am using Android Studio.
What I have done.
1. Downloaded the bundle from https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle
2. Unzipped the bundle to a folder I created.
Opened a blank project in Android studio and followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk  applied to this bundle.

At the end of the day I had an error message

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Cannot evaluate module VitamioBundle-master : Configuration with name 'default' not found.

I have tried several things and repeated the process and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am just at the first step of just importing the library and have not succeeded. Can someone guide me on how to successfully do this in android studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced like your problem. But I try many tricks to import Vitamio to Android Studio and finally succeed.

1. Open or create your project
2. Right click the "app" folder on Project Browser (in the left part of IDE)
3. Open Module Settings (F4)
4. On the Project Structure Window, click plus button on the top left.
5. Choose Import Gradle Projects (press Enter)
6. Open Vitamio project bundle on the source directory form (press Enter)
7. Android studio will build gradle, and then vitamio will be listed under app module.
8. Still on the Project Structure window, enter Dependencies tab and press plus button and choose "Module Dependencies".
9. Click OK, your project should be ready for Vitamio library.

This should work on another module. Hope this helps.

Comment: In the newest Android studio it seems adding the dependency does not work (step 8). You can add it by adding it to your build.gradle file under dependencies with: compile project (':module')